# Dynamic URL to Stay the Same on all Pages

Tags: php, url, dynamic, cookies, session-cookies

so when my url looks like this:

```
http://mywebsitehere.com/?kw=1
```

I am using this code below to do stuff with it:

```
<?php if( isset($_GET['kw'] )){ 
 //my div here
} ?>
```

It works great, and I am getting exactly what I want on the page. However, any link I click on that page will change the url structure and remove the `?kw=1` . Is there anyway to add the `?kw=1` to every link for that session? I have no clue how to do this? Any ideas or answers would be great! Thanks!

Let me know if I need to give more to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set a session variable :

```
if( isset($_GET['kw']) && !isset($_SESSION['kw']) )
{
  $_SESSION['kw'] = $_GET['kw'];
}
```

Then maybe just use the session variable where you need it?

Also dont forget you will need to start a session at the way top of your root document with

```
session_start();
```

this should get you going